# php:Data can posting but can't insert to DB

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

dear all,this is my code at xampp:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO oqc_defect ";
          $sql.= "(Problem_date,       Dept_found,          Line,         Shift,        Time_found,     Model,         Serial_number,       DIC, ";
          $sql.= "Def_class,       Reject_qty,      Symptom,        Cause,       Correction,      Corr_action_plan, ";
          $sql.= "Eff_date) ";
          $sql.= "VALUES ('";
          $sql.= $Problem_date."','".$Dept_found."','".$Line."','".$Shift."','".$Time_found."','".$Model."','".$Serial_number."','".$DIC."','";
          $sql.= $Def_class."','".$Reject_qty."','".$Symptom."','".$Cause."','".$Correction."','".$Corr_action_plan."','";
          $sql.= $Eff_date."')";
```

i try to submit some data to DB. At firebug show "OK 2.6ms", but after i checked my database table still empty.Is the code above not correct?

Comment: echo mysql_error and see what you get

Comment: what you get :
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: Beware of sql injection.

Comment: And please use something like mysql_real_escape. If one of the values holds a ' character your query will fail anyhow.

Comment: @all:i change my quetion

Comment: Which api do you use? (The "old" mysqli module? The slightly less "old" mysqli module? PDO? ...?) `this is my code` - Only a small fraction of it. Please edit your question and include _all_ the relevant code. E.g. the code that creates the connection to the database server; the code that actually sends the query to the MySQL server; something so we can see where e.g. `$Problem_date` comes from; ...

Comment: @VolkerK:i'm using xampp for databse server

Comment: @klox: interesting but a) not my question (but nevermind, you are using mysql_query() -> you are using the old mysql module) b) xampp is not a database system ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK:sorry i'm newbie.haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried this ?

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo your query after the query is constructed. Now we can only guess how the query looks like.

```
<?php
echo $sql;
?>
```